# jQuery datepicker - override options beforeShow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I made this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303431/jquery-datepicker-add-class-depending-on-where-it-appears/6303652), but wasn't sure how to reply to it and still get an answer to my NEW question... so I just made this topic.

Ok so I have my datepicker adding a class above/below on beforeShow, but now I need it to change one of its OPTIONS on beforeShow as well (so that it animates as slideUp or slideDown depending on if its opening above or below).

`inst.settings.showAnim = 'slideUp';` sets the options in the DOM tab on firebug under `DP_jQuery_1308014346347.datepicker._curInst.settings.showAnim` but then it won't show the datepicker.

Actually, I just noticed setting showAnim: 'slideUp' wont even work by itself, does that mean the datepicker won't accept it o_O? Seems a bit weird...

Can anyone help please :)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Changing the calendar animation when it shows?

Comment: Yeah, sorry exactly that. When it shows, if it shows above, I want it to slideUp. If its showing below, I want it to slideDown. 
I have it so that it actually changes the settings value for the _curInst in the DOM, but it doesn't run the animation and it stays hidden...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Don't change the settings in the instance, change it from calling the plugin again.

```
 beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
if (inst.dpDiv.position().top > $(input).position().top) {
        $(inst.dpDiv).removeClass('ui-datepicker-above').addClass('ui-datepicker-below');
        $(input).removeClass('above').addClass('below');
        $('#order-main .datepicker').datepicker('option','showAnim','slideDown');
       } else {
        $(input).removeClass('below').addClass('above');
        $(inst.dpDiv).removeClass('ui-datepicker-below').addClass('ui-datepicker-above');
        $('#order-main .datepicker').datepicker('option','showAnim','fadeIn');
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Where exactly are you trying to set the animation option?

If you are initializing a datepicker with the animation option you write:

```
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker({ 
    showAnim: 'slideUp' 
});
```

If the datepicker has already been initialized then you have to use the second method:

```
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "slideUp");
```

Comment: I'm doing it in the beforeShow function because I want it to detect whether its going to go above or below, and change the animation accordingly. I have the option showAnim: 'slideDown' as default in the settings (in your first example), but then I want it to change to slideUp if its going to be above the input.

Comment: So, as I said, if you're initializing the datepicker use option 1. If it is already initialized, use option 2. Since you are trying to do this in a beforeShow function, it implies that the datepicker is already initialized. Ergo, option 2.

Comment: Do I put $("#myDatePicker").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "slideUp"); in my beforeShow code then??

Comment: Exactly, do that. Experiment.

Comment: Ok, well that works as well in the same way as I had mentioned. It still has the same issue (which I didn't mention) where opening the datepicker works the first time for setting the option to slideDown (when its below), then setting to fadeIn (when its above) but then when you go to try and open it BELOW again, it doesn't work anymore. It just stops opening entirely.

Comment: @Benno: then you'll have to create a small test case for us to investigate. I've no idea what your code looks like. I'd use jsFiddle.

Comment: Can you only extend an instance, and not the prototype? I can't get it working without a specific identifier..?