# jquery ui datepicker position of calendar

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, position

Hi I want to add a class to #ui-datepicker-div. Depending if the div is above or below the input field, the class should be abowe / below

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImage: 'img/icons/calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,           
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {             
            if (inst.dpDiv.position().top > $(input).position().top) {
                console.log('1');
                inst.dpDiv
                    .removeClass('below')
                    .addClass('above');
            } else {
                console.log('2');
                inst.dpDiv
                    .removeClass('above')
                    .addClass('below');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Datepicker - add class depending on where it appears](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303431/jquery-datepicker-add-class-depending-on-where-it-appears)

Comment: maybe, but it dows really work that great. It sometimes work